# docker-compose up -d quiet option to suppres up-to-date

Tags: cron, docker, error-handling

I want to update a docker container in crontab and only get an email if something gets wrong, so I call

```
12 4 * * * cd /var/docker-services/mycontainer/; docker-compose pull -q && docker-compose up -d 2>/dev/null
```

I tried `1>/dev/null` but that didnt suppress the warning

```
mycontainer_app_1 is up-to-date
```

Which is thrown by `docker-compose up`

How can I suppress only that information but still get an email if something gets wrong during `docker-compose up -d`?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess I would suppose that message is coming from the `pull`; you might find success by grouping all the command output and pumping through `grep` to discard the message you don’t want to see. For example:

```
{ cd /var/docker-services/mycontainer/ && /usr/bin/docker-compose pull -q && /usr/bin/docker-compose up -d ; } 2>&1 | grep -vFx "mycontainer_app_1 is up-to-date"
```

Comment: It is thrown by `docker-compose up`. But I will try your idea